# How do I disguise as a teammate using console commands?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-spy

I have some key binds set up in order to make disguising more efficient.  As of now I only have a means of disguising as a member of the opposing team.  I want to make it so I can disguise as a member of one's own team by holding down a key let's say MOUSE3 then pressing the corresponding key pertaining to what ever class one would want to disguise as. I have my code listed below.

```
// Disguise as enemy team
bind "kp_end" "disguise 1 -1"                
bind "kp_downarrow" "disguise 3 -1"              
bind "kp_pgdn" "disguise 7 -1"                
bind "kp_leftarrow" "disguise 4 -1"              
bind "kp_5" "disguise 6 -1"
bind "kp_rightarrow" "disguise 9 -1"            
bind "kp_home" "disguise 5 -1"                
bind "kp_uparrow" "disguise 2 -1"               
bind "kp_pgup" "disguise 8 -1"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2nd argument dictates which team you disguise as. [Source](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Scripting#Auto-Disguise_Scripts)

```
Team
1. BLU team
2. RED team
-1. Opposite team
-2. Same team
```

i.e. while "disguise 3 -1" disguises you as a hostile soldier, "disguise 3 -2" would disguise you as a friendly one.

Edit: So I decided to learn tf2's scripting despite having stopped playing the game.

```
//prepwork. Note: all binds are as requested
echo -----running disguise override. Press +uToggle key for script to work.-----
bind shift +uToggle
alias +uToggle "friendlyDisguises"
alias -uToggle "hostileDisguises"

//shorthands to circumvent nested quotes. e = enemy, f = friend
alias eScout "disguise 1 -1"
alias eSniper "disguise 2 -1"
alias eSoldier "disguise 3 -1"
alias eDemo "disguise 4 -1"
alias eMedic "disguise 5 -1"
alias eHeavy "disguise 6 -1"
alias ePyro "disguise 7 -1"
alias eSpy "disguise 8 -1"
alias eEngi "disguise 9 -1"
alias fScout "disguise 1 -2"
alias fSniper "disguise 2 -2"
alias fSoldier "disguise 3 -2"
alias fDemo "disguise 4 -2"
alias fMedic "disguise 5 -2"
alias fHeavy "disguise 6 -2"
alias fPyro "disguise 7 -2"
alias fSpy "disguise 8 -2"
alias fEngi "disguise 9 -2"

alias friendlyDisguises "bind kp_end fScout; bind kp_downarrow fSoldier; bind kp_pgdn fPyro; bind kp_leftarrow fDemo; bind kp_5 fEngi; bind kp_rightarrow fHeavy; bind kp_home fMedic; bind kp_uparrow fSniper; bind kp_pgup fSpy"
alias hostileDisguises "bind kp_end eScout; bind kp_downarrow eSoldier; bind kp_pgdn ePyro; bind kp_leftarrow eDemo; bind kp_5 eEngi; bind kp_rightarrow eHeavy; bind kp_home eMedic; bind kp_uparrow eSniper; bind kp_pgup eSpy"
```